# Show local notification for selected hours for everyday iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsnotifications, localnotification

I have developed application, I have successfully integrated the code of the local notification. Now I want is to show notification for selected hours only.
For example I want to show notification from 8:00 am to 8:00 pm every day every hours.
so how I can set repeat interval for this task.

Thanks in advance.
Satish

Comment: try giving this as repeat interval <constant for every hour>*<number of hours you wanna skip>

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification`.

To change the repeat interval or disable the notifications, I think your app will have to become active. For example, lets say you want to display the notifications from 8 AM to 8 PM. The 8 PM notification comes up but the user taps the 'close' button on the alert. In this case, I don't think anything can prevent the 9 PM notification from displaying unless your app becomes active between 8 & 9 PM.

In case the user does not close the notification & does come back to your app, you can check the current time & set the `repeatInterval` to 0 (don't repeat).

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Thanks for your replay Akshay, I have set it, it shows every hours, I want to skip some hours from the day. like from 8:00 am to 8:00 pm i don't want notification. If you have code that would be great help.